# Incrementing value in a hash

Tags: ruby, hash

I want to increment the value of the first item by one.  I do not understand why my code is not working

```
puts sales_hash
sales_hash.values[0] = sales_hash.values[0] +1
puts sales_hash
```

I am adding 1 to the first value in `sales_hash`.  When I print out the `sales_hash` the first value remains the same.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Perhaps you want: `h => {:a=>1, :b=>2}; h[h.keys.first] += 1; h #=> {:a=>2, :b=>2}`. It's unusual to use the ordering of a hash's keys used in this way, but you can do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use `Hash#values` you receive an array that contains a copy of all the values in the hash. Therefor, your assignment does not change the hash itself but rather the array containing the values.

Moreover, you should be aware the elements in the hash are ordered by the order of their key's insertion, which might cause unexpected results if you access a certain "position" in the hash since insertions and deletions may change the order of the hash.

If you want to update a value in the hash, you should access it using it's key, for example: `sales_hash[:my_sale] = sales_hash[:my_sale] +1`

Comment: *Hashes enumerate their values in the order that the corresponding keys were inserted.*--But that issue is totally irrelevant to the op's problem.

Comment: @7stud thank you, I have updated the answer to state that more clearly. I believe it is relevant as the OP is attempting to modify a hash by position instead of by key.

Comment: The OP did not say he/she knows what is the first key.

Comment: Or sales_hash[:my_sale] += 1